# SlideUp Callback with passed in variable?

Tags: jquery, callback

```
var ele = $("#container").children().first();
ele.slideUp(1000, function(ele){
    ele.remove();
    $("#container").append(ele);
});
```

The element is not being removed or appended to the container in the callback.  I assume it could be a syntax error, or perhaps I am passing in the 'ele' variable in an incorrect way.  Unfortunately, the scope of the 'ele' variable seems to not be accessible from within the callback, so I'm guessing it needs to be passed in as a parameter.

I am sure one of you experts know the solution, so thought this would be a good place to ask about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `remove` the element explicitly, since `.append()` would shift the element from one place to the other by default.

Try,

```
var ele = $("#container").children().first();
ele.slideUp(1000, function(){ //remove the parameter ele here
  $("#container").append(ele.show());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52mp5t8b/1/)

Comment: Hey I really appreciate the response, but sadly that didn't work either.  :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52mp5t8b/

I would expect that once the 10th div is shown in the container, the 1st one would be at the bottom and the loop would repeat itself, instead the 1st div does not seem to be appended to the bottom.

Hope that makes sense:)

Comment: Haha, just had a major "duh" moment.  Thanks so much.  I assume this means the element was actually being appended as intended, just hidden :P

Will mark this as the answer in 30 seconds, when stackoverflow lets me.